# Facebook graph get user city latitude and longetude

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-fql

I want to get the co-ordinates of the city of user. I can get the name of location using "location" field(not "locations").

How can I get this using Graph API or fql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting back a location id, you can get it using Graph API:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<id>
```

It will look like:

```js
"location": { "latitude": <lat>, "longitude": <lon> }
```

You can also get it using FQL:

```sql
SELECT location FROM page WHERE page_id = <id>
```